# Make executable war files

Tags: jetty, war

Is there any way to make a war file to be executable.I know that we can use jetty runner to execute a war file but what am asking is there any way to execute this war when we double click on it like exe file.

Answer (score 0):

A war file is not meant to be executed, it is meant to be deployed. If you want a shortcut to deploy a war to a server (and optionnaly start this server) you should write a script that does so (using batch as you are on windows).